# Is dandruff an indicator of an "unhealthy scalp?" Can a shampoo cure the underlying problem?

Tags: biology, genetics, hair

In this video (sponsored by Head and Shoulders) by [Veritasium entitled *"What Actually Causes Dandruff?"*](https://youtu.be/TIe2oerd25c?t=318), you can hear Dr. Jim Schwartz a Research Fellow at Head & Shoulders say:

> The dandruff flakes are just an indicator of a fundamentally unhealthy scalp underlying it by any measure you can dream of making

Is this true? The examples of an unhealthy scalp given are:

- Inflammatory Cytokines
- Histamines
- Blood Proteins
- Genes: Immune and Inflammatory Response Genes (upregulated), Lipid Metabolism (downregulated).

The premise of this quote and the remainder of this video is fundamentally that dandruff signifies a bunch of a unhealthy gene expressions which have nothing to do with the mere flakes and that Head and Shoulders shampoo reverses these gene expressions making the user healthy.

[As said by Dr. Jay Tiesman Genomics Group Leader, Head & Shoulders](https://youtu.be/TIe2oerd25c?t=450),

> If you treat with Head and Shoulders after three weeks this [gene] signature looks just like someone who doesn't have dandruff. You're looking at 3700 genes clustered on here flip around, going from an unhealthy signature to a healthy signature.

To keep it simple,

- Does dandruff signify something about your scalp's health?
- Outside of the annoyances of the flakes, can a shampoo remedy these health problems?

Comment: I think there's an implicit assumption here that there is some biological meaning of "healthy" that you can check for. "Health" is a matter of opinion and custom, so if you define "healthy" to be a scalp free of unsightly dandruff flakes, there's nothing wrong with that definition and the claim becomes trivial.

Comment: I think the Q is unclear - 'unhealthy' is a marketing term in this context. If anyone is interested: The source of the colorful gene expression pics in the Veritasium video:  - 
"Volume 166, Issue s2 Special Issue:The Omics Revolution" -  "This supplement was sponsored by Procter & Gamble" it is not made clear whether the usual process of peer review is applied to this sponsored 'special issue' ---- 

The article(a 100% Procter and Gamble sponsored research, by P&G employees in that P&G sponsored issue) : https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2133.2012.10863.x